# How to open ViewPager with specified page. (by default it loads 1st 3 pages)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I use the code:

```
pagerAdapter = new BrochurePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),params);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(6);
```

And I see that my Adapter loads Fragments for pages 0,1,2 and only later for page nr 6. How can I stop it from loading fragments 0,1,2 and make it to load fragments 5,6,7 as it should? (BrochurePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter)